# The link of "Pdf version" on node page does not appear in chrome

Tags: 7, files

I have installed the the print module on my drupal 7 site. I configured the the print module pdf settings.

Now the link "pdf version" is displaying with each node on the content area at bottom. When I click on the link, it save the node in pdf format.

But this only works in firefox. In chrome the "pdf version" link in not displaying.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the permission issue. I granted the permission to the authenticated and anonymous users and it works for me.